Fiori Elements - Controller Extension How to Set Value
I am trying to work with Fiori Element with Controller extension. I have two fields in my entity latitude, longitude which I want to set in onInit or onBeforeSave methods.
entity emptimesbysscat:managed {
key ID: UUID @Core.Computed;
empID: String100;
ticketNo: String20;
emphrs: Int16;
latitude: Decimal(10,8);
longitude: Decimal(10,8);
}

Here is my Controller Extension--
sap.ui.define(['sap/ui/core/mvc/ControllerExtension','sap/m/MessageToast'], function (ControllerExtension,MessageToast) {
'use strict';
var zz_ExtensionAPI;
return ControllerExtension.extend('emptimesbyhierarchy.ext.controller.ExtConObjectPage', {
    
    // this section allows to extend lifecycle hooks or hooks provided by Fiori elements
    override: {
        
        /**
         * Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
         * Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
         * @memberOf emptimesbyhierarchy.ext.controller.ExtConObjectPage
         */
        onInit: function () {
            // you can access the Fiori elements extensionAPI via this.base.getExtensionAPI
            var oModel = this.base.getExtensionAPI().getModel();
        },
        onAfterRendering: function() {
            zz_ExtensionAPI     = this.base.getExtensionAPI();
        },
        editFlow: {
            onBeforeSave: function (mParameters) {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                        
                        console.log(position.coords.longitude);

                        mParameters.context.setProperty('empID','srikanth.pdpl@gmail.com');
                        mParameters.context.setProperty('latitude',position.coords.latitude);
                        mParameters.context.setProperty('longitude',position.coords.longitude);
                    });
                } else {
                    MessageToast.show("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
                }
                console.log(mParameters);
            }
        }
    }
    
});
});

I am not able the set the values.
Thanks
Srikanth
